# Running Windows explorer as admin with different colors

Tags: windows-xp, windows-explorer

I know how to run the explorer on Win XP with admin privileges (for example,
[here is a description on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13805/opening-explorer-shell-with-admin-priveleges-on-xp-with-ie7-installed)). But is there a way to make those admin explorer windows look different from the "normal" user's explorer windows? For example, different background or frame color?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[PrivBar](http://blogs.msdn.com/aaron_margosis/archive/2004/07/24/195350.aspx) will get you what you want, by adding a toolbar that shows your current privilege level.  [Go here](http://blogs.msdn.com/aaron_margosis/archive/2008/08/15/the-return-of-privbar-x86-and-x64.aspx) to get the latest binaries.

Comment: Huh. That's a bit higher-tech than what I've got: I just set the toolbar background image for Administrator to something reddish using TweakUI, which doesn't help when I've used `sudo` and not `runas`...

Comment: ... and it seems to work pretty nicely, so +1!